# Changes are not reflecting instantly in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I need some guidance, I have just started using Kivy and facing a problem in UI.
I have a Button for which I want functionality like this:
     button when clicked connect() function will be called and the Label showing the status will change to "connecting", and when the connection is done  the Label status will  change to the connected.

Here is the problem:
    The Label directly converts to connected, it does not changes to the connecting and then to connected.
   when the function is called in the beginning I am doing this:

Here is what I am doing:

when connecting starts:

```
self.ids.connect_button.text = "Connecting..."
```

once the connection is stablished:

```
self.ids.connect_button.text = "Connected"
```

The screen halts for a while and then directly converts to connected.
Even though there is some time gap but connecting does not appears.

Comment: Show some info. Code or something.

Comment: Well I have tried with  threading and it helped me thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're not actually returning from your function in between setting the Label text each time, with your connection code blocking the execution of the rest of the program until it returns. If this is the case, you maybe want to run your connection code in a thread. It would help to post a full example of what you're doing.

Comment: thanks I have looked at many places and now I too believe that I have to use threading...